# Array of Structs value lost in memory

Tags: c, linux

So, I'm pretty new to C and ran across something a few hours ago that I thought was puzzling.

I'm basically working on a csv file parser in C. I've got the following struct for holding a single value from a csv file. (ex. "5.13" or "Test1").

```
struct CSV_DATA {
    enum { is_int, is_float, is_char } type;
    int ival;
    char cval[10];
    float fval;
};
```

Inside main is the following (Note: lines 40 and 41 are the important ones):

```
int main()
{

   struct CSV_DATA csv_data[500][50];

   char buffer[1024] ;
   char *record,*line;

   int i = 0;
   int j = 0;

   FILE *fstream = fopen("iris.csv","r");

   if(fstream == NULL)
   {
      printf("\n file opening failed ");
      return -1 ;
   }

   while((line=fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fstream))!=NULL)
   {
     record = strtok(line,",");
     printf("%s", record);
     while(record != NULL)
     {

        csv_data[i][j].type = is_char;
        for (int k=0; k < strlen(record); k++){
          csv_data[i][j].cval[k] = record[k];//record;          
        }

        j++;

     record = strtok(NULL,",");
     printf("%s", record);

     }
     ++i;
   }




   return 0 ;
 }
```

The point of this code is to read in values from a csv file and store each one of them inside one instance of CSV_DATA. I then store that value inside a 2d array to be able to access the data later.

Now, this actually stores values into memory. I know because I can see them with GDB, but the problem is that the data is Offset in memory from the actual index of the array.

The following command: x/200ub csv_data ...yeilds the following:

```
(gdb) x/200ub csv_data 
0x7ffffff6b1f0: 2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0x7ffffff6b1f8: 53  46  49  0   0   0   0   0
0x7ffffff6b200: 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0x7ffffff6b208: 2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0x7ffffff6b210: 51  46  53  0   0   0   0   0
0x7ffffff6b218: 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Similarly, x/200ub csv_data[0] yields the same thing...as expected.

However, x/200ub csv_data[1] is looking at the wrong index in memory for the values!! However, I can see them stored in memory, but the index of the array is pointed to the wrong memory location for 1..n. Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You did not `0` terminate your string in `cval`

Comment: `int j = 0;` in only 1 places looks suspicious.  I'd expect it just prior to  `while(record != NULL)`

Comment: thx mch. I'm gonna look into this.

Comment: You want to look up `strcpy` and `strncpy`.

Comment: @chux. This solved my problem! Such a dumb mistake! Thank you.

Comment: @Killingsworth You can post your own answer if you like.

Comment: @chux You should go for it. The points are yours for the taking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inner loop index is only initialized once.  Move `j` index

Other ideas incorporated too

```
int main() {
  struct CSV_DATA csv_data[500][50];
  char buffer[1024];

  //  **FROM**
  //   int j = 0; 
  size_t i = 0;

  FILE *fstream = fopen("iris.csv", "r");

  if (fstream == NULL) {
    printf("\n file opening failed ");
    return -1;
  }

  while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fstream)) {
    char *record = strtok(buffer, ",");

    // **TO**
    size_t j = 0;

    while (record) {
      printf("%s", record);
      csv_data[i][j].type = is_char;

      csv_data[i][j].cval[0] = `\0`;
      // strncat(csv_data[i][j].cval, record, sizeof csv_data[i][j].cval);
      strncat(csv_data[i][j].cval, record, sizeof csv_data[i][j].cval - 1);
      j++;

      record = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
    ++i;
  }
  fclose(fstream);  // add
  return 0;
}
```

[Edit] Corrected code